# Export a dataset to Excel into a named sheet

Tags: export, dataset, excel

I have a dataset:

```
set1 = Dataset[<|"s" -> <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>, "d" -> <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> 6|>|>]
```

My goal is to export several datasets (for simplicity here it is twice the same) into an Excel file. Each dataset shall be in a named sheet. Exporting a dataset to Excel works
(file path is for windows, please change for your system):

```
Export["C:\\temp\\test.xlsx", set1]
```

But exporting a dataset to a named sheet already fails:

```
Export["C:\\temp\\test.xlsx", {"dd" -> set1}]
```

This does not give a table in the Excel-sheet as the first one.

My goal would be to have several named Excel-sheets with each having a dataset. I would expect this to work, but is doesn't:

```
Export["C:\\temp\\test.xlsx", {"dd" -> set1, "FF" -> set1}]
```

How do I get the tables from the datasets into named Excel sheets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `Export["test.xlsx", "DD" -> set1]` does not work to export a `Dataset` to a named worksheet, the syntax does work to export a rectangular data table.  As a workaround, the dataset can be converted to a data table.  One way to convert the dataset to a data table is to export it to CSV format, then import the data like this:

```
set1 = Dataset[<|"s" -> <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>, 
    "d" -> <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> 6|>|>];
ImportString[ExportString[set1, "CSV"], {"CSV", "Data"}]

(*  {{"", "a", "b"}, {"s", 1, 2}, {"d", 5, 6}}  *)
```

Multiple datasets can be exported to an Excel workbook with named worksheets like this:

```
set2 = Dataset[<|"ss" -> <|"aa" -> 1, "bb" -> 2, "cc" -> 3|>, 
    "dd" -> <|"aa" -> 5, "bb" -> 6, "cc" -> Missing[]|>|>];

Clear[convert]  (* converts the dataset to a data table *)
convert[d_Dataset] := 
    ImportString[ExportString[d, "CSV"], {"CSV", "Data"}]

Export["test.xlsx", {
     "Sh 1 DD" -> convert[set1],
     "Sh 2 FF" -> convert[set2]
   }];
```

The exported data can be recovered from the workbook as either a data table or a dataset like this:

```
{names, tables} = Import["test.xlsx", {"XLSX", {"Sheets", "Data"}}];
(* or *)
{names, sets} = Import["test.xlsx", {"XLSX", {"Sheets", "Dataset"}}];
```

Of course, the real test is to open the file in Excel and check the sheet names and the cell data there.

Note that this example uses `Missing[]` to emphasize the need to handle missing data explicitly.  The method also works using, say, an empty string instead of `Missing[]`.  The method works with full rectangular datasets, but does not work with "ragged" datasets.

```
$Version  (* 13.3.1 for Linux ARM (64-bit) (October 19, 2023) *);
```

Comment: It works also for me (Windows with 13.3.0). The Excel file is as expected. Nice work around the exporting importing. Thanks!